# "studied hard on" vs. "studied hard for"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I found one sentence while I was reading a book:

> He did not study hard on the test.

Is this sentence correct in reference to the preposition **'on'** ?

I think the better version is:

> He did not study hard for the test.

Comment: I think you're right and the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We could say "study on a lesson" or "study on Engish", according to [Search in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22study%20hard%20on%22&num=10).

And I think "on" probably means "relating" in this situation. See [ON | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on):

> **on** preposition (RELATING) ​ B1 relating to:
>
> a book on pregnancy
>
> Her talk is on Italian women's literature.
>
> The minister has refused to comment on the allegations.
>
> Criticism has no effect on him.
>
> Do the police have anything on you (= do they have any information
>   about you that can be used against you)?

"Study hard for" is OK.

If "study on a test" is valid, the closest meaning I can find in the dictionary would be "paying". See [ON | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on):

> **on** preposition (MONEY)
>
> A2 used to show something for which a payment
>   is made:
>
> He spent €180 on a hat.
>
> I've wasted a lot of money on this car.
>
> We made a big profit on that deal.
>
> How much interest are you paying on the loan?

So "study hard on a test" is probably wrong.